# a problem with the onclick javascript for this button or link was encountered

Tags: community, salesforce1-app

[image]

I am getting the error when i click on Custom Button in Record Detail page here i am posting my code

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/21.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/21.0/apex.js")} 
 if({!ISPICKVAL(KEvents__Transaction__c.KEvents__Gateway__c,'PayPal')}) { 
   var result = sforce.apex.execute("KEvents.KPPaypalProcessor","doRefundPayment",{objtransaction: "{!KEvents__Transaction__c.KEvents__TransactionID__c}"});
   alert(result); 
 }else{ 
  var result = sforce.apex.execute("KERegistrationCntr","KPRefund", {transactionId:"{!KEvents__Transaction__c.Id}"}); 
alert(result); 
} 
 window.location.reload();
```

Comment: The problem is with KERegistrationCntr class .Please share the class and method and method parameters .Problems looks to me in that

Answer (score 1):

In the Else condition Namespace before Class name is missing,By adding nameSpace KEvents issue is fixed.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/21.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/21.0/apex.js")} 
 if({!ISPICKVAL(KEvents__Transaction__c.KEvents__Gateway__c,'PayPal')}) { 
   var result = sforce.apex.execute("KEvents.KPPaypalProcessor","doRefundPayment",{objtransaction: "{!KEvents__Transaction__c.KEvents__TransactionID__c}"});
   alert(result); 
 }else{ 
  var result = sforce.apex.execute("KEvents.KERegistrationCntr","KPRefund", {transactionId:"{!KEvents__Transaction__c.Id}"}); 
alert(result); 
} 
 window.location.reload();
```